# How to make QML ToolBar always visible?

Tags: android, ios, qt, qml

i try to make some chat messenger app for Android and iOS.

I have TextInput in the bottom of the screen.

When i tap on this TextEdit, On-Screen keyboard showed and all application window scrolled to the top. MenuBar and ToolBar scrolled in the up direction too and go beyond top of the screen.

I need some interface area (for example ToolBar or MenuBar, or something else), which should always be visible in the top of the screen, even when On-Screen keyboard showed.

How i can do this in QT cross-platform project?

I cannot post screenshot because It requires 10 rep points, but i hope i explained situation.

Here is the code:

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Controls 1.3
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.2

ApplicationWindow {
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true

    menuBar: MenuBar {
        Menu {
            title: qsTr("&File")
            MenuItem {
                text: qsTr("&Open")
            }
            MenuItem {
                text: qsTr("E&xit")
            }
        }
    }

    ToolBar {
        Text {
            text: "ToolBar test text"
        }
    }

    TextEdit
    {
        anchors.left: parent.left
        anchors.right: parent.right
        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
        text: "Enter text"
    }
}
```

Thanks, Evgeny